# What's a $O(n^2 \log n)$ algorithm that decides if a distinct set is completely triangulable?

Tags: complexity-theory

Let $P$ be a finite set of $n$ distinct   points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The set $P$ is called completely   triangulable if for any three points $p, q, r \in P$ the area of their triangle is always positive.

An algorithm that determines if a finite set $P$ is completely triangulable returns **TRUE** if  $P$ is completely triangulable and **FALSE** otherwise.

What is an algorithm that runs in $O(n^2 \log n)$ time?

My thinking is to use breadth first search but the running time of it is $O(n^2)$, so how can I edit that to achieve $O(n^2 \log n)$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term *triangulable*, but does it basically mean that no three points in $P$ should be collineair?

Comment: Additionally, I don't think that Breadth First Search runs in $O(n^2)$ but rather $O(b^d)$ where $b$ is the branching factor of the search tree and $d$ its depth. It is unclear to me  how your search tree would look like, most likely it will have depth $d > 2$. How would your search tree look like? How do you want to apply BFS for this problem?

Comment: @Auberon I was thinking the exact same thing.

Comment: @SoSo Ma Could you also tell us why you think that there is a $O(n^2 log\, n)$ algorithm? You you have a paper reference for that?